# visual studio 2015 intellisense

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have problem with intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 .axml and .xml  files.
I have downloaded:

- android-layout-xml.xsd
- schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd

and moved them into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas` and included them in visual studio through `XML->Schemas->Add` dialog and in that dialog these schemas are shown and marked as used but intellisense still doesn't work.

XML->Schemas->Add dialog

[image: XML->Schemas->Add dialog]

Intellisense after adding them

[image: Intellisense after adding them]

I have event tried to download through Extension and Updates XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms but no success. I would appreciate any help and thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it partially. I had unblock those .xsd files in \installation path\Xml\Schemas\ but now intellisense for .xml files is not correct

Comment: Go to schema website.  The is a full definition of the xml properties.  Make sure your definition matches the website.